# How to change simple javascript confirm into a Jquery dialog box confirm when deleting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am tying to create a Jquery conform dialog box for delete confirmation. The problem is it doesn't work when I do the Jquery stuff. I am going to post the javascript confirm box so that I can learn on how to change it into the Jquery dialog box confirm.

```
    //for delete confirm box
 var del = function($element) {
    $('.remove').dialog({
        title: 'Delete',
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        width: 350,
        height: 275,
        buttons: {
          "Delete item": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $element.data('allow', true); // Allow the next click to proceed
            $element[0].click(); // Hit the DOM native click event
          },
          Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });
    }

    $('.delete').click(function(e) {
      if (!$(this).data('allow')) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        del($(this));
      }
    });

    $('.delete').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.delete').hide();
    });
```

PHP code:

```
<tr align='center'> 
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['BookID'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['Title'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['Author'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['PublisherName'];?></font></td>
        <td><font color='black'><?php echo $test['CopyrightYear'];?></font></td>    
        <td><a class="edit" href='view.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>' title="Edit">Edit</a>
        <div id="register" ></div>
        <td><a class="delete" href ='del.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>' title="Delete"><center>Delete</center></a> <!----for deleleting ---->        
        <div id="remove" ></div>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'does not work' - what happens and what do you expect? (best edit that into the question)

Comment: The jQuery dialogs work asynchronously, so unlike the  confirm dialog it doesn't wait for a response before the next line of code runs. You have to restructure your code to use callbacks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: the confirmation dialog doesn't show when I do the Jquery dialog box. It only works when I use the simple javascript confirm.

Comment: So can you post what you tried with jquery confirmation dialog?

Comment: The jQuery Dialog works nicely but is not a trivial change from what you have. Guess you are going to have to do some research as play with it a bit

Comment: You might want to make another confirm dialog box, than if your script is fired show that custom box and return value from there to your script. Actually you want to know how to style confirm box, and you tho you can simply do it with jQuery?

Comment: I updated my post about jquery confirmation dialog but it doesn't work when I click the delete button. Please take a look at my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

The (only?) advantage of `confirm()` is that is happens synchronously and no other code proceeds until you select an answer. This allows you to return the result from a click handler to decide if the click should proceed.

Any custom method of displaying a dialog requires the code to continue, else the dialog will not render. This means all interaction with dialogs has to be asynchronous. You need to respond to the yes/no answer many frames later.

### One solution:

- Stop the click event from proceeding (unless a certain property is present)
- Open the dialog
- Get a yes/no answer
- If the answer is yes set a flag on the element to allow the click to proceed normally, then simulate a click event on the original element.

Now jQuery Dialog does not support this out of the box, but it would not be hard to write.

**Working Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/f9u500zr/

```
$('.del').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).data('allow')) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    del($(this));
  }
});
```

and in the dialog settings I set the flag and click the button again:

```
buttons: {
  "Delete item": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    $element.data('allow', true); // Allow the next click to proceed
    $element[0].click(); // Hit the DOM native click event
  },
```

### Notes:

- I simply store an `allow` data flag on the button to let me know the next click should be allowed to proceed.
- As this example uses click handlers for the delete and the prompt, I use `stopImmediatePropagation` to stop the command processing. For links or forms you would want to use `e.preventdefault()`
- For `stopImmediatePropagation` to work in this example, the order that the events are registered *is* important. If you reverse the order of the tow event handlers at the end of my example, you will see the item deleted then the dialog appears! e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/f9u500zr/1/

Comment: the confirm box immediately disappears after I click the delete in the table.

Comment: @HelpMe: With which example? Can you confirm the first example I gave you works in your browser? (if not which browser)

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` doesn't work it deletes and disappears immediately

Comment: @HelpMe: Again: Please confirm which link/code you are testing and with which browser?

Comment: I'm using the first example and I applied it to the codes that I posted. Please take a look at my GUI [please click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6swhohcc80ete8p/problem.png?dl=0)

Comment: @HelpMe: As I am not psychic, I cannot see how you have used my *working* example in your own project :) You need to post the latest source code you are testing, e.g. at the end of your question.

Comment: please take a look at my [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmbrlcbv3c58hep/index.php?dl=0)

Comment: @HelpMe: Right away I see you have a duplicate `id="register"` everywhere, so jQuery will only match the first `#register`. Please correct the simple things first. Please also save out your `output` HTML (e.g. saved from a browser) as I cannot mentally compile PHP into HTML :)

Comment: the id="register" is for add and edit only. `<td><a class="delete" href ='del.php?BookID=<?php echo $test['BookID'];?>' title="Delete"><center>Delete</center></a> 
    <div id="remove" ></div>` that is for delete

Comment: @HelpMe: Please listen carefully. Valid HTML does not allow multiple ID in a page. I am suggesting things that you *must* change too. Please provide output HTML so I can mockup your page in JSFiddle.

Comment: Problem solved my mistake is I didn't used the `e.preventdefault()`